# List files in which a word has disappeared

Tags: git, grep

So, say I have two branches `old_release` (containing an old release) and `new_release` (containing a new release). In the old release there was a tool called `cook`, I think it's still in the new release, but it's been renamed. I need to work out what it's been renamed to.

I would like a list of files which must satisfy the criteria;

1. File exists in both `old_release` and `new_release`.
2. String `cook` is found in the version from `old_release`.
3. String `cook` is not found in the version from `new_release`. I need this condition because most of the code is not updated and will contain defunct references to `cook`.
4. My repository is big, and checking out a branch takes a long time. I'd like a solution that avoids that.

My current solution looks like;

```
git checkout old_release
grep cook . -R -l -I > old_release_cooks.txt
sort -o old_release_cooks_sorted.txt old_release_cooks.txt
git checkout new_release
grep cook . -R -l -I > new_release_cooks.txt
sort -o new_release_cooks_sorted.txt new_release_cooks.txt
vim -d old_release_cooks_sorted.txt new_release_cooks_sorted.txt
```

This meets all my requirements apart from point 4. It requires I do at least one checkout. Strictly I guess it doesn't create a list of files that differ, but the diff is close enough.

Is there a way to get this list without checking out?

Comment: `git grep` can search a commit, and `git diff` with two commit hash IDs will compare the files *in* the two commits and adding `-S cook` will show only files where the *number of occurrences* of the match *change*, up or down. You could combine these two facts to use `git diff` to get a list of candidate files to search, and then `git grep` just those files in the new-release version.

Comment: (Remember to add `--name-status` or similar to the `git diff` to get the list of file names and whether the files are new, deleted, or simply modified. To make this Industrial Strength, use `git diff-tree -r` instead of the user-oriented `git diff` and to choose whether you want rename detection.)

Comment: If you sort `old_release_cooks.txt` and `new_release_cooks.txt`, you could show which files "lost" cook by using `comm -2 -3 old_release_cooks.txt new_release_cooks.txt` (comm prints 3 columns: lines only in 1st file, lines only in 2nd file, lines in both files. `-2` and `-3` will suppress the second and third columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout-free one-liner in bash that uses `git grep` and evaluates its results using `comm`:

`word='cook' rel1='old_release' rel2='new_release'; comm -1 -2 <(git grep -l '\b'"$word"'\b' "$rel1" | sed 's/^[^:]*://' | sort;) <(git grep -L '\b'"$word"'\b' "$rel2" | sed 's/^[^:]*://' | sort;)`

EDIT: adjustments so that also your condition 1. is satisfied (file must exist in both)

EDIT2: simplified expression

Comment: big quality of life improvement, this is now a function in my bashrc, thanks

Comment: You're welcome :) I wonder how long it takes on a big repo like yours (especially compared to old method). So feel free to share timings - If you have taken any :)

Comment: If it's still slow, the last part (listing files in new release) could be my made faster for sure. E.g, by grepping for ^ or using a completely different git command that doesn't need to actually open the files.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay on getting back to you. Just made the comparison; I go from 1m40.135s to 0m3.941s. So that would be 25 times faster. Incredible!

Comment: Also, I'm not doing 2 checkouts for the comparison, I'm assuming that I start on one of the branches I'm interested in. So with two checkouts we would probably be about 50 times faster.